# Error while connecting to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance on GCE VM with Knex.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Knex.js to connect to a Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance, and I have double checked all my information a million times at this point with just a complete lack of understanding about why this error is happening. Here is my code:

```js
const connectWithUnixSockets = (config) => {
    const dbSocketPath = "/cloudsql"
  
    // Establish a connection to the database
    return Knex({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: {
        user: 'postgres', // default user provided by google
        password: Config.DBPass, // password for the account
        database: 'ceclub', // database name
        host: `${dbSocketPath}/Connection-name`,//I have checked this part a thousand times, it's correct.
      },
      // ... Specify additional properties here.
      ...config
    });
  }
let config = {
    pool: {
        max:5,
        min:5,
        acquireTimeoutMillis:60000,
    },
    createTimeoutMillis:30000,
    idleTimeoutMillis:600000,
    createRetryIntervalMillis:200
}
 let knex = connectWithUnixSockets(config);
```

Before it gets asked I did just copy this from the gcloud functions documentation. I've made sure to give myself admin permissions and the service account for my VM admin permissions for Cloud SQL, and I have authorized the IP of my VM. However, everytime I run this program I end up with the following issue:

```
Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/connection-name/.s.PGSQL.5432
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/cloudsql/connection-name/.s.PGSQL.5432'
}
```

I have double checked the documentation a bunch and I am just at a loss for what I might have messed up. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You mention both Cloud Functions but also a VM, so it's not clear to me which you are using to try to connect.

In Cloud Functions, the environment provides a `/cloudsql` directory for you that connects to your instance.

If you are running locally (or in a different enviroment such as a GCE instance), you can use the Cloud SQL proxy to create a similar directory. Check out the source code for the sample you referenced (with instructions for running with the proxy) in this [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/postgres/knex#launch-proxy-with-unix-domain-socket) repo.

Additionally, you can check out the "[Authorization with the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-proxy)" page for detailed instructions on how to use the proxy.